# .htaccess to change url to a part of a querystring and append with .html extention

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, title

I am trying to change the following URL:

```
   http://localhost/app/site/?page=12&module=custom&title=Swat_Medical_College-_The_Project_of_Swat_Medical_Complex
```

To this URL:

```
   http://localhost/app/site/12/custom/Swat_Medical_College-_The_Project_of_Swat_Medical_Complex.html
```

I have tried too many options to make it functional but in vain...

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/(\d+)/([a-z-]+) index.php?page=$1&module=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

it throws an 404 error page not found...
Please help me to solve the above url conversion thanks in advance.
Also please if there is any easy and basic tutorial regarding url rewriting, i will be really very appreciate it. thanks

Comment: A basic tutorial? Take a look at the documentation. It is very technical, yes. But it is also very well written, extremely precise, and comes with really good examples. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: **"Also please if there is any easy and basic tutorial regarding url rewriting"** Do you have google on your country ? http://bit.ly/1NZFXwV

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your expression `RewriteRule ^/(\d+)/([a-z-]+) index.php?page=$1&module=$2&title=$3 [L]`. I would write it `RewriteRule ^/(\d+)/([a-z\-]+) index.php?page=$1&module=$2&title=$3 [L]`. The character `-` is a special one if you use it between `[]`. Please let me know it this helps you

Comment: ok let me check it quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the rule you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/app/site/(\d+)/([a-z-]+)/(.+)\.html$ /app/site/index.php?page=$1&module=$2&title=$3 [L,B]
```

That would do what you sketch in your question. I am not sure though if that really is you situation. But you will probably be able to adapt it to your needs.

For details I can only recommend to take a look into the official documentation of [Apache's rewriting module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), as mentioned in the comment above. It is very technical, yes. But it is also very well written, extremely precise, and comes with really good examples.

Comment: your answer is perfect, that's great @arkascha. thank you